# I build a interpreter on a language with a garbage collector. I need a garbage collector for the interpreter?

Tags: garbage-collection, programming-languages, interpreter

This is a naive question, but in the tutorials I have seen so far is not spelled clearly.

If I build a interpreter on top a high-level language (not C, C++, etc) and this have a garbage collector... is necessary to also make one for the interpreter itself?

And if the answers is yes... it must be the same kind of the host? (ie: If the host is mark-sweep, the interpreter too?), or is possible to leverage the host and let it manage all of this?

The selection of host make a difference? I plan to use F#/.NET, but is the same for Java and others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory management of the interpreted language can piggy-back on the memory management of the host, but if you are implementing a non-toy interpreter, you may need to use *[weak pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference)* for the administrative references from the host to values of the interpreted world that should be garbage-collected if there are no references to them left in the interpreted world.

If you are implementing a toy interpreter, no one may even notice if you use strong pointers for administrative references from the host world to the interpreted world. In this case, I would recommend you don't bother: weak pointers, as a feature, are available in all sufficiently advanced memory-managed languages, but the details differ and their use is always tricky. [Bruno Haible's survey](http://www.haible.de/bruno/papers/cs/weak/WeakDatastructures-writeup.html) provides a picture of all the varieties. In his survey, this use of weak pointers falls under “Global garbage collection: Allow garbage collection to work across process boundaries, or across a Lisp - C/C++/Java foreign interface boundary”, except that the foreign interface boundary is between the host language and the interpreted language.

Comment: What separate a toy from a "non-toy" in this area? How know what is necessary to be a weakref or not?

Comment: @mamcx 1) A non-toy interpreter, no one is going to use long enough to notice a memory leak (the only consequence of using a strong pointer where a weak pointer would have been appropriate is a memory leak). 2) In the implementation of the interpreter, anything that would cause a memory leak if it were implemented with a strong pointer should be a weak pointer :) (it really depends on the characteristics of your interpreted language. In the best case, you need no weak pointer at all).

Comment: Ok, what "characteristics" could requiere a weak pointer? Any sample or reference? Is my intention to avoid complications as far as possible.

Comment: @mamcx Weak references are needed if for whatever reason the interpreter needs to maintain a list of interpreted-world objects (variables, communication channels, functions, …). Then the fact that these variables, communication channels, functions … are referenced in a table prevents any of them to be reclaimed, even if they are no longer referenced from the interpreted world. In this case the interpreter has effectively created a memory leak by recording all the variables, … in a strong table. The interpreter should have used a weak table instead.

Comment: Ah, so the values inside of the interpreter not need them (ints, list, objects, etc, things in the scope) but the objects that are build for support the interpreter need it (everything on the AST like functions, modules, etc)?. Is better to store everything on a weak table from the start?.

Comment: JavaScript lacks weak references--a fact which makes it very difficult to avoid memory leaks in certain kinds of event-based code.  As to whether JavaScript should be called a toy...

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. But you might have exceptions, e.g. because the memory semantics of the interpreted language is different of the memory semantics of the language you are coding the interpreter in.

As an example, some languages are garbage collecting threads or tasks. If you code your interpreter for such a language in Java, you'll need to GC the tasks by yourself.

You probably want some weak hash tables.

Comment: Which are the "memory semantics" to be aware of? As I say, the host is F#/.NET and the interpreter is close to F# (semi-functional, inmutable by default, mutability ok, imperative, relational). I will have scalars, arrays of things, list, tables (in the relational sense) and interop with databases/files/etc. Wish to have generators/coroutines or Actors/CSP.